# jQuery Mask function for input date

Tags: jquery, date, mask

I have to put a mask in an input which the user will insert a date: dd/MM/yyyy

I am trying to use $('#inputField').mask('00/00/0000') to do so.
The problem is that i need to evaluate at every time the user press a key to check if the date is correct like:

30/02/2018 
- the user should not be allowed to press '2' in MM if he/she puts 30 in dd.

**I tried that translation object but it gets every part separated:**

```
$('#inputField').mask('AA/SS/YYYY', {'translation': {
    A: {pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/},
    S: {pattern: /[A-Za-z]/},
    Y: {pattern: /[0-9]/}
  }
});
```

Does anybody know how i can handle this without using a external library/plugin?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to add a `keyup` or `keydown` method to your input, and then write a date validation function that fires each time. Can you explain what exactly you're having trouble with, or what you've already tried towards this? It's great that you've included code, but the input mask doesn't seem to be related to the validation you're asking about.

Comment: Hi Tyler, i've tried this:
$('#inputField').mask('00/00/0000', {'translation': {
    A: {pattern: /[1-3]/},
    S: {pattern: /[0-9]/},
    Y: {pattern: /[0-9]/}
  }
});
But i get dates like 12/99/9999 passing. I need to check every time if the date is correct. I have a Regex which does all the evaluation including leap years:
(^(((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[\/](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[\/](0[4,6,9]|11)))[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[\/]02[\/](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)
but does not work too.